# Using loops in R to identify unique cases varying on factor variable

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I am still struggling with using if and while loops in real-world datasets. Below is a example dataset. My dataset includes customer IDs and where they purchase their coffee.

```
customers <- data.table(customer_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), store = c("starbucks", "peets", "coffee bean", "drnk", "starbucks", "coffee bean", "peets", "coffee bean", "drnk", "starbucks"))
```

What I would like to do is create a loop function that allows me to identify customers who are going elsewhere for their coffee. In this dataset, customer 1 is going to both starbucks and coffeebean.

What I did was next was assign a store_id to each shop in case my loop function will rely on numeric values. Starbucks is 1, Peets is 2, Coffee Bean is 3, and DRNK is 4.

```
customers <- data.table(customer_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), store = c("starbucks", "peets", "coffee bean", "drnk", "starbucks", "coffee bean", "peets", "coffee bean", "drnk", "starbucks"), store_id_value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1))
```

In my loop function, I was hoping to do something like.. for each customer, if store_id_value of the first purchase is EQUAL to the store_id_value of their next purchase, then continue performing this function til the end. For customers who are purchasing coffee at different locations, this would return a false. Thus, I would like to create a column that shows these TRUEs and FALSEs instead of discontinuing the code.

In my actual dataset, I have about 40k unique customer IDs. Any suggestions on how to get this started? Any packages? Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: Why not just use `table` to make a table of how many times each customer visited each location? You can use that to identify customers that only visit a single location.  A for loop doesn't seem like what you need here.

Comment: I could, but I have over 40K unique customer IDs. I am looking for something efficient that will only return customer IDs that are shopping at more than one location.

Comment: Is your data coming in from a csv? Or is it in a database to start?

Comment: I am uploading a CSV file.

Comment: `customers[,.(multiple_shopper=length(unique(store))>1), by=customer_id][multiple_shopper==TRUE,customer_id]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `library(dplyr)` you could use `mutate()` or `summarise()` like this with `n_distinct()`:

```
library(dplyr)

customers %>% group_by(customer_id) %>%
    mutate(shopping_faithful = n_distinct(store) == 1)

Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
Groups: customer_id [5]

   customer_id       store shopping_faithful
         <dbl>       <chr>             <lgl>
1            1   starbucks             FALSE
2            2       peets              TRUE
3            3 coffee bean              TRUE
4            4        drnk              TRUE
5            5   starbucks              TRUE
6            1 coffee bean             FALSE
7            2       peets              TRUE
8            3 coffee bean              TRUE
9            4        drnk              TRUE
10           5   starbucks              TRUE
```

[This](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf) is a good resource for `dplyr` functions.

Comment: I like this output, but it gave me this error: Error in mutate_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default

Comment: Make sure you remove the `+` at the beginning of the continued line that was copy/pasted into the code (it mimics what you see at the terminal).

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`, we can use `uniqueN` to find the distinct number of 'store' for each 'customer_id' and assign (`:=`) it to new column after converting to a logical `vector`

```
customers[, shopping_faithful := uniqueN(store)==1, customer_id]
customers
#    customer_id       store shopping_faithful
# 1:           1   starbucks             FALSE
# 2:           2       peets              TRUE
# 3:           3 coffee bean              TRUE
# 4:           4        drnk              TRUE
# 5:           5   starbucks              TRUE
# 6:           1 coffee bean             FALSE
# 7:           2       peets              TRUE
# 8:           3 coffee bean              TRUE
# 9:           4        drnk              TRUE
#10:           5   starbucks              TRUE
```